# Angular 2: How to hide button only on selective iteration of *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have following HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor='let product of products'>
     <td>
            <button [hidden]="hidebutton" (click)="Follow(product.Id)">Follow</button>                           
     </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And corresponding click event in my Typescript followproduct.component.ts:

```
@Component({
   ---
   ---
})
export class followproduct implements onInit{
hidebutton: boolean = false;
Follow(productId: number) {
        ---
        this.hidebutton = true;      
    }
}
```

Upon clicking on Follow button of one product, all the buttons of other product in iteration gets hidden-and that's obvious too, as I am allotting the hidden option to iterative button tag.

Is there any way to hide, update or change the button of only selective iteration of *ngFor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make hidebutton an array. Something like this

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor='let product of products'>
        <td>
            <button [hidden]="hidebutton[product.Id]" (click)="Follow(product.Id)">Follow</button>                           
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And in your controller

```
@Component({
   ---
   ---
})
export class followproduct implements onInit{
hidebutton: any[] = [];
Follow(productId: number) {
        ---
        this.hidebutton[productId] = true;      
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this does not work in my code. In fact, it stops displaying other iterations altogether.

Comment: I've edited the example ngFor demo to suit your needs. works as my code above But I had to change isHidden from any to any[]. http://plnkr.co/edit/E00kPmnzKb7Lql4iWa26?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

That's because all product share same variable named **hidebutton**. What you have to do is, create a new variable for each product as shown below,

```
<tr *ngFor='let product of products'>
     <td>
            <button [hidden]="product.hidebutton"                           
           (click)="Follow(product.Id,product.hiddenbutton)">Follow</button>                           
     </td>
</tr>
```

---

```
export class followproduct implements onInit{
//hidebutton: boolean = false;
Follow(productId: number,hidebutton:boolean) {
        ---

        //if(hidebutton==false)

        hidebutton= true;

        //hidebutton =!hidebutton;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how product,hidebutton, flag, and product.hiddenbutton are related.I am unable to determine the flow.

Comment: You create one one product object property called **.hiddenbutton** for each product object dynamically. **Flag** is just a parameter variable to receive value, you can use any other name instead.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Actually this still isn't working in my code-it is not taking the property dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

give your buttons an id (what you should do anyway) and use that.

```
<tr *ngFor='let product of products'>
     <td>
            <button [hidden]="hidebutton==='button'+product.Id" (click)="Follow(product.Id)">Follow</button>                           
     </td>
</tr>
```

And in the controller

```
@Component({
   ---
   ---
})
export class followproduct implements onInit{
hidebutton: string= '';
Follow(productId: number) {
        ---
        this.hidebutton = 'button'+product.Id;      
    }
}
```

Something like that should work

**Update**

Sorry I never used Angular2 or typescript before, so I'm not aware of the syntax. Maybe it works like this.

Comment: _hidebutton===button{{product.Id}}_ :It seems this is syntax of Ionic 2 and is not working in my HTML. Do you have alternative syntax?